adding a word in vocabulary Pytorch
I'm using an Image Captioning model and I'm fine-tuning it to specific images I give him, but the problem is some words that I put on the captions do not exist on the coco 2014 dataset.
What do you recommend doing to add the word to the vocabulary?
